# N Factor model for health profile similar to OCEAN

Tags: health-education

Is there a standard for breaking down a person's health profile in to a small number of most relevant factors? Something similar to how OCEAN(Big5) decomposes a person's personality into 5 traits.

It should be something that has obvious dimensions, like nutrition,exercise and mental, and have a standard questionnaire to be answered.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, and by the tag it appears to be for the purpose of approaching teaching it in a memorable way.  The same way that many different people have proposed ways to break down personality into categories/factors, similarly there are many perspectives via which to look at health.  I am not sure if this question will yield the answer that you seek, especially since neither a single answer exists, nor is a comprehensive answer possible as there is not exactly a standard per se.  Specifying in your question that you seek an EXAMPLE of it might be best.

Comment: What about pulse, blood pressure and oxygen saturation? If anyone is wrong with any of these three values, you’re in trouble.